# meaning of words and tefillah

Tags: tefilla, sources-mekorot, words, kavana-concentration

The *Kitzur Shulchan Aruch* (6:1) tells us, *“When one makes a **berachah** he should have in mind the **meaning** of the **words**.”* Is there any *halachic* source (i.e. *Kitzur Shulchan Aruch, Shulchan Aruch* or *Mishnah Berurah*) that says when one *davens* he should know the meaning of the words?

Comment: _Mishna B'rura_ O.C. 60:11 says that one must know the meaning of the words of the first _pasuk_ in _Sh'ma_. This specificity is based on the opinion of R. Me'ir in a 3-way dispute over how much of the first paragraph requires such intent. Elsewhere he says that the same applies to the whole first paragraph in the _amida_ and might imply that it is also true of _p'suke d'zimra_.

Comment: Also see the Mishna B'rura in 60:7, and Rashba on B'rachos 13a. They corroborate my previous comment.

Comment: Isn't davening made up of brakhot?

Comment: @DoubleAA, you know well that "davening" a/k/a "_t'fila_" (in the usual meaning of that word) is not entirely _b'rachos_ (even if what _Chazal_ called "_t'fila_" is).

Comment: @msh210 So the question is only about those parts which aren't Brachot? Doesn't that invalidate AY's answer?

Comment: @DoubleAA AY's answer refers to "_Sh'ma_".

Answer (score 3):

Learn [kuntres hateffilah](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=43281&pgnum=1) from the Rebbe Rashab Z"L. It explains it in detail and it is not a very big maamar. Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Which parts of davening are essential to have kavannah by? (i.e. know the meaning of the words)

Comment: Alter Rebbe writes in Tanya that your obliged to have kavana during the posuk shema yistoel and the first beracha in the amidah (magein avrohom)

Answer (score 1):

There is a source which says that when one davens he need not know the meaning of the words.

[The O Ch Mishna Berura 101 [14]](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14170&st=&pgnum=260&hilite=) on the law about praying in any language says

> “But in Hebrew, one performs one's obligation even if he does not
>   understand the language”.

O Ch 101 speaks about the Amidah. The Shaar Hatziyun there refers to O Ch 62 which refers to the Shema.